# Dynamically Add/Edit Table HTML Table Rows

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table

This is driving me nuts, I've been trying all sorts of Javascripts and codes all day and can not get this to work, so hoping someone here can point me in the right direction please.

Here is my current table, and I want to create an "advanced" option that allows for other details to be added per row

[image: simple table]

So then if you click "advanced" it will expand out to these features, as well allowing you to add or delete additional rows

[image: expanded table]

Here is the table code that I am trying to get to with the expanded view:

```html
<table border="0" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <th>First Name</th>
      <th>Last Name</th>
      <th>Hourly Rate</th>
      <th>Contract Until</th>
      <th>Advanced Details</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">John</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">Smith</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">$
      <input type="number" name="number57" id="number57"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="date" name="date" id="date"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Advanced"></td>
    </tr>
       <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">
        <label for="select">Project ID:</label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">$
        <input type="number" name="number57" id="number57"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="date" name="date" id="date"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add"> / 
        <input type="button" name="button4" id="button4" value="Remove"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">Bob</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">Jones</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">$
      <input type="number" name="number58" id="number58"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center"><input type="date" name="date2" id="date2"></td>
      <td style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="button2" id="button2" value="Advanced"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">Tom</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">Collins</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">$
      <input type="number" name="number59" id="number59"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="date" name="date3" id="date3"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="button3" id="button3" value="Advanced"></td>
    </tr>
   
          <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">
        <label for="select">Project ID:</label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">$
        <input type="number" name="number57" id="number57"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="date" name="date" id="date"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add"> / 
        <input type="button" name="button4" id="button4" value="Remove"></td>
    </tr>
          <tr>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">
        <label for="select">Project ID:</label>
        <select name="select" id="select">
          <option value="1">1</option>
          <option value="2">2</option>
          <option value="3">3</option>
        </select></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center">$
        <input type="number" name="number57" id="number57"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="date" name="date" id="date"></td>
      <td bgcolor="#F2F2F2" style="text-align: center"><input type="button" name="button" id="button" value="Add"> / 
        <input type="button" name="button4" id="button4" value="Remove"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align: center">&nbsp;</td>
      <td style="text-align: center"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Submit"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Where is your `javascript/jquery` code? Please add it to your post as text.

Comment: I don't have any setup, this was all done hardcoding the table.  The js and jquery code I've been trying to get to work isn't going well, but probably because I don't understand what I'm doing :(

Comment: add the JavaScript code. you don't expect us to write the whole code for you, do you?

Comment: I will echo the need for some javascript/jquery with this question.  You will get little help without it.  It doesnt need to be working, it just needs to show what you are attempting and how.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to suggest advice without some example code, but I think this does something similar.

https://jsfiddle.net/3gkwoe7j/4/

One note on dynamically adding elements, you need to attach the event listener to something static in the DOM, and then use a selector. (I assume you're using jQuery, since you tagged it in you question) So in my example:

```
$('.table')
    .on('click', 'button.advanced.toggle', function() {
    $(this)
      .text(this.textContent === "LESS" ? "ADVANCED" : "LESS")
      .parents('.person')
        .find('.advanced.section').toggle();
  })
```

I bind a click listener to the `.table` and then filter by the selector `button.advanced.toggle`.

Hope that helps.